# Where is the documentation what $mailable string of is Mail::assertNotQueued()?

Tags: laravel, email, mocking, phpunit

I've been doing some mail tests in Laravel this morning, which worked.

Now I wanted to test the queue and saw `Mail::assertNotQueued(...)`

like it says in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mocking#mail-fake). The method requires a $mailable string. See [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/MailFake.html#method_assertNotQueued) the details. But I looked over the docs and I didn't find anything that says what this 'mailable string' is...

Doing `Mail::assertNotQueued(new WorkflowEMail());`, obvioslly faild, because class != string.

Here my Test Class:

```
class WorkflowEmailTest extends TestCase
{
use DatabaseMigrations;

/** @test **/
public function an_workflow_email_is_send()
{

    //$this->markTestSkipped('must be revisited.');
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    Mail::fake();

    Mail::assertNotQueued(new WorkflowEMail());

    Mail::to('test@apitest.test')->send(new WorkflowEMail());

    Mail::assertQueued(WorkflowEMail::class,1);

}
```

Can anyone point me to the docs or tell me how to test this properly?

Answer (score 0):

All the mock methods require a `class` string to be passed into it, the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#mail-fake).

```
Mail::assertNotQueued(WorkflowEMail::class);
```